# textcolor change while typing in textview ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, textview, nsattributedstring

[image]

I am using textview for colored text typing .

when choosing a color and typing, the color should continue to appear until placing a period

you see how after I placed a period(.) after "hello" the "Hhh" is still red? so I'm saying that after place a period(.) the color should default back to black.

```
- (BOOL)growingTextView:(HPGrowingTextView *)growingTextView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
 if ([text isEqualToString:@"."]) {
    txtMessage.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
}
}
```

this code made all text in black color.

How can i manage this feature in Textview ?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `textViewDidChange` method of your `UITextview`

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) { //Handle the text changes here
   if textView.text!.lowercased().range(of:".") { // Check your textview string has "." then set black color 
      // set black color 

        let splitStringArr = textView.text!.characters.split(separator: ".", maxSplits: 1) // split first match "."

        if splitStringArr.count > 0 {
            let redString = splitStringArr[0]
            let blackString = splitStringArr[1]
            if redString.count > 0 {
               myMutableString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: redString, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 18.0)!]) // set font as you like
               myMutableString1.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range:NSRange(location:0,length:redString.count))                
            }
            if blackString.count > 0 {
               myMutableString2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: redString, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 18.0)!]) // set font as you like
               myMutableString2.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.blackColor(), range:NSRange(location:0,length:blackString.count))   
            }
            [mutableAttString1 appendAttributedString:newAttString2];
            labName.attributedText = myMutableString1
        }
        else {
             // set red color 
        }

   }


}
```

Comment: i have tried that.. this makes my whole textview color black. i just want black color after dot (.)

Comment: Wow then you should convert by yourself. I'm giving you hint thanks

Comment: :D  m trying to convert ..  red is not compulsry color, it can be green,blue etc